# Grails JSON.registerObjectMarshaller

Tags: json, spring, grails, groovy

I need to change the format for a json response.  I have a simple domain class, GeoCounter, mapped against a database table that looks like:

```
import grails.rest.Resource
import groovy.transform.ToString

@Resource(uri="/fieldvaluecounters", formats=['json'])
@ToString
class GeoCounter {
String id
int value

static transients = ['geoCountry']

static mapping = {
    table 'geo_counter'
    id  name: 'geoCountry', column: 'geo_country', generator: 'assigned'
    value column: 'numOfHits'
    version false
}

static constraints = {
    id(unique:true, blank: false)   
 }

void setGeoCountry(String geoCountry) {
    id = geoCountry
}

String getGeoCountry() {
    return id
}

}
```

and I need this returned:

```
    `data = [{key: "twn", "value": 3 },
            {key: "gbr", "value": 1 },
            {key: "en", "value": 4}];`
```

My spring resources.groovy has:

`omnitureMarshallerRegistrar(MarshallerRegistrar)`

and the Marshaller has:

```
class MarshallerRegistrar {
    @PostConstruct
    void registerMarshallers() {
        println "Registering customer marshallers"
        JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(GeoCounter) { GeoCounter gc ->
            return [
                key: gc.getGeoCountry(),
                value: gc.getValue()
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

but my method 
`/poc/api/fieldvaluecounters`

still returns id & value instead of key, value.  What am I missing?

```
[ 
{
id: "twn",
value: 3
},
{
id: "gbr",
value: 1
},
{
id: "en;q=0.8",
value: 1
},
{
id: "en;q=0.5",
value: 8
},
{
id: "jpn",
value: 36
},
{
id: "idn",
value: 1
},
{
id: "chn",
value: 2
},
{
id: "fra",
value: 11
},
{
id: "en-AU;q=0.8",
value: 1
},
{
id: "usa",
value: 2
}
]
```

Comment: What is the predicament in just using `[key: gc.id, value: gc.value]` in marshaller?

Comment: That was my first attempt.  I just switched back to    return: [
    key: gc.id,
    value: gc.value
   ] but its the same result.  I know the marshaller is registered because I get, "Registering custom marshallers" from my log output but it doesn't seem to be invoking the transformation on my requests.

Comment: Can you create a sample app replicating the issue which can be investigated?

Comment: Can you remove `@Resource` annotation just for testing? Maybe it overwrites it somehow? Also, can you put some logging statement inside `JSON.registerObjectMarshaller` closure block?

Comment: What is the Grails version you use? Registering marshallers via @PostConstruct or afterPropertiesSet() was fixed in 2.3.12 and 2.4.4, take a look at jira - https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11116

Comment: I agree with @SzymonStepniak. What about registering it in `BootStrap.init`?

Comment: Thank you Szymon!  That worked to move the code to the Bootstrap.init. I am on 2.4.3 using GGTS.  When trying to upgrade to 2.4.4 I couldn't get the groovy-all-2.3.7 to work as eclipse was expecting 2.3.6. Removing @Resource did not work but moving the marshaller to Bootstrap.init worked.